# Reactjs: How to get a css-class attribute from a mounted <div>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Lets say I have a react DOM element like this one:

```
render () {
  ...
  return (
    <div className = "widePaddingRight" style = {{width: "100px"}}
      ref = "pickMe"
    >
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

CSS:

```
.widePaddingRight{
  paddingRight: 20px
}
```

If I access this element later and try to get its width like that:

```
componentDidMount () {
  var elem = this.refs.pickMe.getDOMNode().getBoundingClientRect()
  console.log(elem.width)
}
```

I get `120` in my console. My expected result was `100`. Since I have to calculate with the original width I have to get the padding-attributes of the element.

**Question:** How can I get the `paddingRight` attribute of my component in my react-class?

**Update**
With the input of @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans I was able to solve the underlying problem (thank you for that): Just add `box-sizing: border-box` to the CSS. Now `getBoundingClientRect()` gives `100` instead of `120`.

I still dont know how to get a css class-attribute from a mounted div - any suggestions?

Comment: Counter question: [why do you need to?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) if you're using React, you shouldn't need to mess with the styling of your component unless a `props` (from the parent) or `state` (from the component itself) change occurs, at which point your `render()` function is responsible for generating the "what it should now look like" ReactJS code, which React then uses to generate a diff, applying only the difference between old and new content to the DOM.

Comment: And on a more HTML/CSS/JS technical point: right click on the element in the browser, hit "inspect element" and look at the computed box model. How big does the browser say it is? There are [two ways to do box sizing in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/); the old quirky model will yield 100px, the modern default model will yield 120px.

Comment: Think on a div that can be resized by the user by dragging the mouse at its corner from left to right. You would add a kind of `new_width` prop during dragging (state) that is used in the `render()` method.

Comment: No you wouldn't. You'd make the div responsible for its own resizing by giving it a resize handler, and then as the user drag-resizes the component, which calls the resize handler, you process the "what it should now be" width based on the event values, then bind the new width you compute using `this.setState({ width: computed})`, and then you have the render function generate the appropriate content, `<div style={{ width: this.state.width }} ......`

Comment: thats exactly what I am doing. You need an initial width to make this work.

Comment: Do that by clamping in getInitialState, not by rendering to the DOM, then looking at what the browser made it, then binding, which then has to rerender: `getInitialState: function() { return { width: 100 }; }, render(): ....`, and now render will only be called once, with your state being consistent from the moment the component is created. (the code you're showing does not use `this.state.width` in the render function, so make sure to fix that)

Comment: The above is a simplified example. The component gets its style as part of a `{...this.props}` call actually. Thank you for your input but lets focus on my question please.

Comment: Never simplify to the point that the code in your question is radically different from the code you **actually** work with. As for the actual problem, I already told you to check your box-model. Using the modern browser box model your element's computed bounds are based on CSS margin + CSS border width + CSS padding + CSS width. Not just margin + border + width.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93102/discussion-between-benvorth-and-mike-pomax-kamermans).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

```
const style = window.getComputedStyle(React.findDOMNode(this.refs.pickMe));
```